# Excel: Problems w. INDIRECT, Arrays, and Aggregate Functions (SUM, MAX, etc.)

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, aggregate-functions

**Objective**

I have a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet containing a price list that may change over time (`B2:B5` in the example).  Separately, I have a budget that too may change over time (`D2`).  I am attempting to construct a formula for `E2` to output the number of items that can be purchased with the budget in `D2`.  Thereafter, I'll attempt to construct formulas to output any change that would be made (`F2`) and a comma-delimited list of purchasable items (`G2`).

*Note: It unfortunately isn't possible to add an intermediate calculation column to the list, such as a running total.  As such, I'm trying for formulas for single cells (i.e., `E2`, `F2`, and `G2`).*

*Note: I'm using Excel for Mac 2019.*

```
       A         B       C       D         E         F                  G
  +---------+---------+-----+---------+-------+---------+---------------------------+
1 |  Label  |  Price  |     | Budget  | Items | Change  |          Item(s)          |
  +---------+---------+-----+---------+-------+---------+---------------------------+
2 | Item #1 | $ 10.00 |     | $ 40.00 |     3 | $  4.50 | Item #1, Item #2, Item #3 |
  +---------+---------+-----+---------+-------+---------+---------------------------+
3 | Item #2 | $ 20.00 |     |         |       |         |                           |
  +---------+---------+-----+---------+-------+---------+---------------------------+
4 | Item #3 | $  5.50 |     |         |       |         |                           |
  +---------+---------+-----+---------+-------+---------+---------------------------+
5 | Item #4 | $ 25.00 |     |         |       |         |                           |
  +---------+---------+-----+---------+-------+---------+---------------------------+
6 | Item #5 | $ 12.50 |     |         |       |         |                           |
  +---------+---------+-----+---------+-------+---------+---------------------------+
```

For `E2`, I've attempted:

`{=MAX(N(SUM(INDIRECT("$B$2:$B$"&ROW($B$2:$B$6)))<=$D2)*ROW($B$2:$B$6)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$6))+1)}`

Though, the above values and this formula result in an output of `-1`.

*Note: The formula for `F2` and `G2` *seemingly* easily follow `E2`; e.g. `{=$D2-SUM(IF((ROW($B$2:$B$6)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$6))+1)<=$E2,$B$2:$B$6,0))}` and `{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,INDIRECT("$A$2:$A$"&(MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$6))+$E2-1)))}` seem to work well, respectively.*

**Observations**

- `{="$B$2:$B$"&ROW($B$2:$B$6)}` evaluates to `{"$B$2:$B$2";"$B$2:$B$3";...;"$B$2:$B$6"}` *(as desired)*;
- `{=INDIRECT("$B$2:$B$"&ROW($B$2:$B$6))` *should* evaluate to the equivalent of `{{$B$2:$B$2},{$B$2:$B$3},...,{$B$2:$B$6}}`; though, as a 1x5 multi-cell array formula, evaluates to the equivalent of `{#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!}` and, with `F9` does to `{10;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;12.5}`;
- `{=SUM(INDIRECT("$B$2:$B$"&ROW($B$2:$B$6)))<=$D2}`, as a 1x5 multi-cell array formula, evaluates to the equivalent of `{TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE}`  *(as desired)*; though, with `F9` does to `#VALUE!`;
- `{=N(SUM(INDIRECT("$B$2:$B$"&ROW($B$2:$B$6)))<=$D2)}`, as a 1x5 multi-cell array formula, evaluates to the equivalent of `1;1;1;0;0` *(as desired)*; though, with `F9` does again to `#VALUE!`;
- `{=N(SUM(INDIRECT("$B$2:$B$"&ROW($B$2:$B$6)))<=$D2)*ROW($B$2:$B$6)`, as as 1x5 multi-cell array formula, evaluates to the equivalent of `{2,3,4,0,0}` *(as desired)*; though, with `F9` does to `{#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!}`;
- `{=N(SUM(INDIRECT("$B$2:$B$"&ROW($B$2:$B$6)))<=$D2)*ROW($B$2:$B$6)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$6))+1}`, as a 1x5 multi-cell array formula, evaluates to the equivalent of `{1,2,3,-1,-1}` *(as desired)*; though, with `F9` does again to `{#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!}`; and,
- `{=MAX(N(SUM(INDIRECT("$B$2:$B$"&ROW($B$2:$B$6)))<=$D2)*ROW($B$2:$B$6)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$6))+1)}` evaluates to -1

Interestingly:

- If `{=N(SUM(INDIRECT("$B$2:$B$"&ROW($B$2:$B$6)))<=$D2)*ROW($B$2:$B$6)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$6))+1}` is placed as the multi-cell array formula in, say, `E10:E14`, a `=MAX($E$10:$E$14)` results in `3` *(as desired)*.

**Speculation**

At present, I'm speculating that, when entered as a single cell array formula, the `INDIRECT` is not being assessed to be array producing and/or the `SUM`, as part of a single cell array formula, is not producing an array result.

Please assist.  And, thank you in advance.

**Solutions (Thanks to Contributors Below)**

- For `E2`, `{=IF($B$2<=$D2,MATCH(1,0/(MMULT(N(ROW($B$2:$B$6)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW($B$2:$B$6))),$B$2:$B$6)<=$D2)),0)}` (thank you Jos Woolley);
- For `F2`, `=IF($E2=0,MAX(0,$D2),$D2-SUM($B$2:INDEX($B$2:$B$6,$E2)))` (thank you P.b); and,
- For `G2`, `=IF($E2=0,"",TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,$A$2:INDEX($A$2:$A$6,$E2)))` (thank you P.b).

Comment: You're making the mistake of assuming that piecemeal evaluation of subsections of a formula via committing with `F9` within the formula bar will correspond to the formula evaluation as a whole. What's more, I cannot reproduce some of your evaluations at my end (using Excel Office 365): I have no idea how `INDIRECT("$B$2:$B$"&ROW($B$2:$B$6))` could return - via evaluation with F9 - `{10;#N/A;#N/A;#N/A;12.5}` for you; I would expect, and indeed get, `{10;10;10;10;10}`. But this is besides the point.

Comment: My question would be: are you looking for an explanation as to the behaviour you see, or for an alternative solution? Your use of `INDIRECT` is unecessary here.

Comment: The priority would be finding a standalone / single cell formula for `E3` (aside from a user-defined VBA function).  Secondarily, I'd very much like to understand why the approach I tried isn't working.  What alternative to `INDIRECT` do you suggest?

Comment: Use the Solver - think there is a similar problem on here about products.

Comment: I was under the impression that Excel Solver operates on variable cells, leveraging established fomula and conforming to established constraints.  In this case, I have variable-length range and no established formula.  Is Solver truly applicable in this case?

Comment: This is where Excel 365 functions like Scan are a lot more convenient for doing running totals etc. - at a price, I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first point to make, as I mentioned in the comments, is that it must be understood that piecemeal evaluation of a formula - via highlighting subsections of that formula and committing with F9 within the formula bar - will not necessarily correspond to the actual evaluation.

Evaluation via F9 in the formula bar *always* forces that part to be evaluated as an array. Though this is misleading, since  the overall construction may not actually evaluate that part as an array.

The second point to make is that `SUM` cannot iterate over an array of ranges, though `SUBTOTAL`, for example, can, so replacing `SUM` with `SUBTOTAL (9`, in your current formula should work.

However, you would still be left with a construction which is *volatile*, so I would recommend this non-volatile alternative:

`=MATCH(1,0/(MMULT(N(ROW(B2:B6)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B6))),B2:B6)<=D2))`

Comment: Both solutions seem to work quite well, thank you!!  So, my multi-cell and `F9` evaluations were indeed misleading in so far as they *forced* array evaluations for formula sections that wouldn't otherwise have evaluated to arrays!?  And, by *volatile*, are you referring to the fact that `INDIRECT`s are re-evaluated with every worksheet change; or, are you referring to the fact that cell and range references won't reflect changes, such as shifting all columns to the right?

Comment: Correct re your first comment. Re volatility, no - here's a link. https://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm

Comment: Nice non-volatile solution!

Comment: Though, an upside of the `SUBTOTAL` w. `INDIRECT` solution is that one can variably specify the source sheet and table, and visibility and filtering will factor into rows considered, no!?

Answer (score 1):

In `E2` you can use:
`=MATCH(TRUE,--SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2:B6,,,ROW(B2:B6)))>=D2,0)`

In `F2` you can use:
`=D2-SUM(B2:INDEX(B2:B6,E2))`

In `G2` you can use:
`=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,A2:INDEX(A2:A6,E2))`

[image]

Comment: For the first formula better to use Jos Woolley's non-volatile solution

Comment: Yup, Jos' non-volatile solution for `E2` works well, and natively supports budgets that exceed that total cost of all items.  That said, your solutions for `F2` and `G2` are FAR cleaner.  I was somewhat blindly fixated on the path I was on for mine.  Thank you!!